# Mystery short in piezo driver circuit

Tags: 555, short-circuit

I'm building a circuit to drive a 113 kHz piezoelectric mister. When I apply power, it appears the circuit is shorted. My regulated lab power supply hits the 1 A limit I set, though it should consume much less power.

I've replaced each component separately, including the breadboard, but the problem persists. Here's the schematic:

[image: Driver schematic]

I assume the problem is obvious, but I've been over it a dozen times and I can't see the issue. Can any of you true EEs spot my mistake?

- I'm using a regulated lab power supply, not a wall wart.
- I've replaced every single component more than once, so it's unlikely to be a fried component issue.
- Fixing stupid mistake on power symbol in schematic
- The 555 gives a nice 113 kHz square wave on the oscilloscope. If I disconnect the 555 from the FET and drive the FET with a cheapo function generator, that circuit is fine as well. Combining the two through the 10 ohm resistor is where the trouble starts.

Comment: The FET seems to short trough L1 when turned on. Is this intentional?
Also, are your components (555 and the FET) good? If they are fried, they can cause all sorts of problems.
Did you verify the signal at the gate of the FET?
Lastly, your power supply connection on the schematic is strange at least.

Comment: This isn't a "spot the mistake" situation. It's a "learn debugging" situation. Next time you make one, set current limit to 50mA, and don't fit R1. Test the 555 is working as you expect before fitting R1. Consider what the max current through L1 will be.

Comment: @Sasszem I've verified an replace every single component more than once. They're definitely good. I've verified the FET signal too. Power supply symbol is wrong; I'll fix that.

Comment: Disconnect sections to isolate the short with a DMM or series R in the supply.  If you don't have experience you would test the 555 first then the FET then the load.. High 5 @Andyaka  same here, except 741's in Uni in the early '70. Also it will drift down about 1kHz per 100 hrs when you get it working and will fail at -2kHz unless you make it self resonant.

Comment: All - *Please be nice* and make sure to comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending - or worse. Some comments already had to be deleted. Polite [constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) is allowed  - with the emphasis on *polite* and *constructive*. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The 555 gives a nice 113kHZ square wave on the oscilloscope. If I disconnect the 555 from the FET and drive the FET with a cheapo function generator, that circuit is fine as well. Combining the two through the 10ohm resistor is where the trouble starts.

Comment: Tip: SI units named after a person are lowercase when spelt out and have the first letter of their symbols capitalised. So, 'Hz', not 'HZ'. Also SI standard recommends a space between the numbers and units same as "2 socks", not "2socks".

Comment: Sounds like the output of the 555 may be getting overloaded by the gate capacitance of the IRFZ44. This question is above average because you included a good schematic with reference designators. Thanks for that! Try a larger value resistor (like 100 Ohms and even 1 K) at R1. See if that at least restores proper oscillation. Then if it does, take a look at the gate of IRFZ44 and see if it seems acceptable.

Comment: @mkeith I just tried 10, 100, and 1 K. Same result unfortunately. I quickly reconnected my cheapo signal generator to the gate just to verify that the amplified circuit works as expected, and it does. It draws 50 mA.

Comment: There are so many bugs with this design, it would fill a page.   Add a power resistor in series with piezo like 1 Ohm 10 Watt, find resonant frequency and get load nF, gate pF=1900 pF  Your FET is probably pulsing kW.  Use a 10 turn pot or add fixed resistors , Use variable duty cycle to pulse the resonator with a self-tuned oscillator.  I could go on....  You are driving the impedance of the Piezo ESR (< 1 Ohm as a short circuit out of resonance.  It cannot work like this !!!

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The circuit I'm using has been used successfully in 4 places that I know of (thanks Google), one of them a commercial product.

Comment: @AlanGibson with the exact same parts? The piezo could mess things up badly if it's not the same.

Comment: Do you have 'scope traces of the MOSFET gate and drain, while it's operating with the function generator (which works), and while it's operating with the full combined circuit (and malfunctions)?

Comment: Try 15ohm + in place of L1.

Comment: @Sasszem They all use the common 113 KHz piezo mister that you find on Aliexpress, Amazon, etc. I can't be for certain they are exactly the same, but they look it. All other components are exactly the same.

Comment: What is the duty cycle of the rectangular waveform emanating from the 555? Is L1 going in to saturation? If L1 is saturated, it will appear as a short.

Comment: @qrk Duty cycle is approx. 60%. I'm thinking L1 is the problem because that's what let the magic smoke out before I turned down the current limit. I'm using the radial DIP type. Maybe I should go to a larger one or an iron core.

Comment: @AlanGibson You may be better off using a half-bridge driver for the piezo element and using a series tuning inductor which will increase the voltage across the piezo element. You won't have a DC current component to worry about, just the AC voltage component across the inductor with regards to saturation.

Comment: SHow us your layout and all scope signals like , Vgs, Power using proper test methods and ESR,DCR of all passives. Otherwise you are asking us to guess, when it should be obvious.

Comment: If the power supply is current limiting, the whole thing is invalid. When the power supply current limits, the voltage rail crashes, so who knows what might happen.

Comment: Just for fun and to prove you are not crazy, replace L1 with a resistor (like 10 k) and just probe everything with the scope to see if it is working. Then you can try 1 k. Then 100. Mind the power dissipation in the resistor when you get to 1 k or 100 Ohms. This is intended as a confidence booster. But it also gives you a chance to see if any bad trends develop as the load current is increased. This may produce some kind of insight.

Answer (score 1):

You Must show / define the reference design power source, which is critical.  It may be 100W or much more. Not 15W. Think of how much power a tweeter would need to do the same to water.

Perhaps your support is just too weak and it was performing normal or your layout was far too inductive with long wires.  The supply dI/dt is massive and limited by the sum of ESR's across the supply with T=ESR * C initially then it ramps up.

Perhaps your driver is too high input capacitance Miller capacitance and the load is feeding back to the gate. The low ESR of some undefined mister has larger capacitance, and this feeds back to the gate and requires tuning.

### Debug Steps

Step 1 is insert a series R <=1 Ohm 10W with Piezo ground to monitor and limit current and/or reduce voltage to prevent power limit for now.

Step 2 is adjust for low duty cycle with 100k pot from V+ to 0V to TRIG or a fixed R for testing. Eventually you will want about 50%

Step 3 is find resonant frequency and monitor current then reduce resistance 0.1 Ohm, Now the Q is high and power is increasing then make it as small as the FET  Ron

Step 4 is jumper the R and watch the piezo mister or something else smoke., do not resonate in air (damage)

Step 5 is make an injection locked loop oscillator using the 50 mOhm shunt resistor circuit then add a 7 uH inductor to resonate with the ground connection of the 10nF Cap for 600 kHz adjust L as necessary for phase/freq.

[Here](https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2011/555-footstool/)'s what [I would do with a 555](https://farm6.static.flickr.com/5304/5884246614_8de73e3379.jpg) [image]

For kicks, [watch this good engineer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKhPj7uFD0Y&t=0s) admit he made a fool of himself trying to make it work. Then decided on a simple 555 timer in the next video. I would not.  You will learn a lot and that is valuable but more costly in time and materials.

[Much later he posted his final solution starting](https://youtu.be/OOZi3QnnDCo?t=367) with a 555 NFET then going to a half bridge then back to 555 with Step Current limit and a half sine relaxation cycle.

But seriously, it is better to make a Pierce Oscillator of out it with a BPF to avoid harmonic resonances.  But the circuit they sell costs < $1 in materials and is not very repeatable or reliable.  The resonant frequency will drop 1kHz / 100 hrs of operation then fail at -2kHz unless self-tracking with current limiting. [Research](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Xinyi-Zhong-2/publication/304996762_Perpetual-operation_Frequency_Response_and_Equivalent_Circuit_Modelling_of_Piezoelectric_Ultrasonic_Atomizer_Devices/links/577e5b3d08aeaa6988b0c326/Perpetual-operation-Frequency-Response-and-Equivalent-Circuit-Modelling-of-Piezoelectric-Ultrasonic-Atomizer-Devices.pdf?_sg%5B0%5D=CrW5zWPt-QKJ_jdN8q4BdLGVUyGA86gfRIsv4APwkhccMD4VqF6eCiaWYBCyj_ijLiYDYrX2qvbulJKpQ-lCPw.djOcisLLL0andkhMIs8rjDdBB8k3R5Hkr10S0Jk9rk1zDiZKRrxEg7ZbWOcau9DGxzxDNnsaBWX3wq7g007LSA&_sg%5B1%5D=2gAZhqa-BBllyvlxjkEmT2vXeM3NQwOi8sLLCnWhzsY5dDPnX0fQppciW44ho5SLROl7CVXfwIdbb1lojeDk3qlOBZqcDwjrlDGVTN7S2iXr.djOcisLLL0andkhMIs8rjDdBB8k3R5Hkr10S0Jk9rk1zDiZKRrxEg7ZbWOcau9DGxzxDNnsaBWX3wq7g007LSA&_sg%5B2%5D=wp7p1k_g5B6-YdytLZhLBpdyGzTjJ2pOCbOApQfJaOYDNC7YUvrYBgMSb_EWqhjkD_Tmvboew34IhRA.gy5zdAv5pFiQymob52Ukas-Z0ipTLWu1gRI8lyXIY2LsiFlg1A8YkJa0_OJAr2CgzIgYNxJ9typZAA_-E26cLA&_iepl=)

Comment: The last video you linked is what I based my circuit on. If you jump to 8:37 you'll see the schematics are virtually identical. Therein lies the mystery of why his works and mine doesn't.

I'll give your suggestion a go while waiting for inspiration to strike for a fix for the current one.

Comment: Are your supply currents , layout and component types identical (Mylar cap)?  If not , there are a few problems that will occur as the resonance is not like an 8 Ohm tweeter but around 100 mOhms. est. ballpark.  Series resonance is not mystery.